# How to optimize a regex pattern?

Tags: java, regex, text, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm trying to fetch substring(s) from a text and using regex for it. 
Sample text:

```
bla bla 1:30-2pm bla bla 5-6:30am some text 1-2:15am
```

I'm looking for the time frame entries(1-30-2pm...). Made them bold for readability only

Here's my regex:

```
\d{1,2}(:\d{1,2})? – \d{1,2}(:\d{1,2})?(am|pm)
```

java snippet:

```
public static List<String> foo(String text, String regex) {
    List<String> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        entries.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return entries;
}
```

Can you help me optimize the regex pattern? There might be some use cases that i missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we like to optimize our expression, we might want to add optional spaces, just in case our inputs might have any additional spaces, other than that, your expression looks great:

```
(\d{1,2})(:\d{1,2})?(\s+)?-(\s+)?(\d{1,2})(:\d{1,2})?(am|pm)
```

We have also added capturing groups, if we wish to get the data.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/46crBc/1/)

Or:

```
(\d{1,2})(:\d{1,2})?(\s+)?(am|pm)?(\s+)?-(\s+)?(\d{1,2})(:\d{1,2})?(\s+)?(am|pm)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/0TRn4X/1/)

whichever would be desired.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(\\d{1,2})(:\\d{1,2})?(\\s+)?-(\\s+)?(\\d{1,2})(:\\d{1,2})?(am|pm)";
final String string = "bla bla 1:30-2pm bla bla 5-6:30am some text 1-2:15am\n"
     + "bla bla 1:30 - 2pm bla bla 5  - 6:30am some text 1 - 2:15am";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired and you wish to modify it, please visit this link at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/46crBc/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for jex.im

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a regex like

```
String regex = "(?i)(?<!\\d)(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?::[0-5]\\d)?\\p{Pd}(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?::[0-5]\\d)?[ap]m\\b";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HApBrb/3)

**Details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive flag (for `AM`, `PM`, `am`, `pm` values etc.)
- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately to the left is allowed
- `(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` - an optional `0` and then a digit from `1` to `9`, or `1` and then `0`, `1` or `2`
- `(?::[0-5]\d)?` - an optional group: a digit from `0` to `5` and then any one digit
- `\p{Pd}` - any hyphen
- `(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(?::[0-5]\d)?` - see above
- `[ap]m\b` - `a` or `p` and then `m` and a word boundary.